# Why can we not see the whole graph of functions like $y=mx+c$ or $y=x^2$?

Tags: functions

When you produce a graph of $y=mx+c$ or $y=x^2$ you can not show the whole graph. However small the scale and however large the screen or the paper, the graph will eventually spill over the edge. Why? Please give an explanation with descriptive example of a graph.

Comment: Infinite domain, finite observable universe.

Comment: There are an infinite number of inputs for many functions.  If you only considered integer inputs, is there a largest input you can use?  If so then you can scale the Cartesian plane accordingly.  But if there is not a largest input, how can you scale the plane to cover all viable inputs?

Comment: You *could* apply something like an extreme [fish-eye lens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisheye_lens) to a graph and represent infinite distances in finite space, much one sees in works by artist [MC Escher](https://www.mcescher.com/gallery/recognition-success/circle-limit-iv/). However, while the crowding of infinitely-many artistic elements into a finite space may be aesthetically pleasing, the extreme distortion this causes in function plots isn't particularly helpful in studying those plots.

Comment: Like the  the graph of  $y=1$ it needs infinite domain of paper to plot all of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question isn't really about graphs.

Most first grade classrooms have an integer number line posted on the wall. It usually goes up to about $20$. Do you wonder why it doesn't show the *whole line*? Could it, if you put the numbers just an inch apart?

As the kids learn to count they learn to imagine how the line goes on forever.

Comment: It does make sense, anyway well said.

Answer (score 2):

Because the domain is infinite (as is the range in these cases), and you do not have an infinite screen.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a function $f:X \rightarrow Y$, the graph of $f$ is the set
$$\Gamma_f = \{(x,f(x))| x\in X\}.$$  It is a set of ordered pairs $(x,y)$, where $x$ comes from $X$ and $y$ comes from $Y$.  Note that for real functions, we can only show a window that is a portion of the graph.

Comment: I'd argue this answer is throwing notation at a question in which the level of the confused reader (either OP or someone stumbling across this with the same question) is not quite high enough to make a big distinction between the domain, codomain, and graph of a function. Especially with the Gamma notation for the graph, I'd guess this will just serve to confuse anyone who doesn't already know the answer to the OP's post. Out of goodwill and the fact your answer *is* correct, take a +1 anyway :)